# Recommended UI/UX conference in the UK?

Tags: conferences

Completely ripped off and copied from [@wnathanlee](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/1144/wnathanlee)'s [question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/recommended-ui-ux-conference-in-the-usa), but I thought it was such a good question I wanted to do a UK version...

I know there are some great conferences/sessions/symposiums/seminars out there on the subject of User Interface Design and Web Usability. If I had to pick **one** to go to within the next year, which one should it be? And why?

A few disclaimers:

- I would be restricted to a conference inside the United Kingdom
- Recommendations based on experience of **actually attending** are preferred
- One conference per answer, please

Comment: Please make this question community wiki.

Comment: @Rahul - and why is that? Show me where it explains that questions like this should be community wiki. And "because that's how Stack Overflow does things" is not a valid response.

Comment: @Charles this is not a UI related question. It is a question directed at the UI community. and btw "because that's how Stack Overflow does things" is a valid response IMO

Comment: Updated to community wiki, as requested

Comment: @Charles The practice of making "list" questions CW is well established on UI at this point. http://ui.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1 You make a good point though. It should be added to the FAQ.

Comment: @Sruly - I disagree. Stack Overflow is to the point where people just mark things as community wiki because they want to ask a question there that they know doesn't actually belong there. Either a question belongs there or it doesn't. As for this question, how is a question about UI related conferences not related to UI? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Patrick, just because it is done a lot doesn't mean that it's the right way to do things. Maybe this question belongs in community wiki, because it is on topic (contrary to what @Sruly thinks), but is more informational, but my point still stands - making posts you deem "off-topic" community wiki is not appropriate. Off-topic posts should not be kept on the site.

Comment: @Charles This question in not a UI question it is a "UI related" question. It is close enough to the topic at hand and interesting enough to the users of this site that it will not be closed, but it is not 100% on-topic. If you want to argue that this should be considered on topic write about it on Meta

Comment: @Sruly, you do know that you just contradicted yourself, right? First you said that this is not a UI related question, and now you say it is a "UI related" question. What's the difference?

Comment: @Charles A UI question is something related to interfacing with a user. Going to a conference will help you become a better better UI expert but it will not fix a UI problem

Comment: @Sruly And where does it state that this site is exclusively for what you define as a "UI Question"?

Comment: @Sruly - Also, how do you explain your own contradiction? You don't even seem to know the difference between the terms that you are using to define what is on-topic and off-topic here.

Comment: None of this discussion belongs on this question.  The original issue with CW should have been asked on Meta along with the discussion regarding UI/UX/User Interface semantics.  If you feel that you can contribute the community, you should follow the correct procedure.  Being argumentative rarely achieves anything.

Comment: @LoganGoesPlaces sorry, your argument is flawed. If what you state here is "right" then the original comment that the post should be CW doesn't belong here either. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: Blimey - I wasn't expecting that!

Answer (score 2):

Haven't been to it in the UK specifically, but [Usability Week](http://www.nngroup.com/events/edinburgh/agenda.html) is always a good conference, and it is in Edinburgh in late October.

Answer (score 2):

I've thoroughly enjoyed the two [UXCampLondon](http://uxcamplondon.org/)s I attended in 2009/2010.

You can look at the [presentations from the 2010 event](http://www.flickr.com/photos/otrops/4527344009/in/set-72157623874986616) (hover over the picture for links to the slides).

Had a fantastic time, met a bunch of really nice people, put real faces to some folk I'd only talked to online, and learned a lot. Recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It's not specifically a UI/UX conference but the [DIBI Conference](http://www.dibiconference.com/) (Design It, Build It) certainly has elements of User Focused designed in all of its talks. I went to the one last year and found it really inspiring.