# Recommended UI/UX conference in Europe?

Tags: conferences

Really liked [@wnathanlee's USA-question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/recommended-ui-ux-conference-in-the-usa), and it's [UK-counterpart](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/recommended-ui-ux-conference-in-the-uk) but I would like to broaden the field a bit.

I know there are some great conferences/sessions/symposiums/seminars out there on the subject of User Interface Design and Web Usability. If I had to pick **one** to go to within the next year, which one should it be? And why?

A few disclaimers:

- I would be restricted to a conference inside Europe
- Recommendations based on experience of **actually attending** are preferred
- One conference per answer, please

Answer (score 5):

2012 should feature another "The Web and Beyond" in The Netherlands (probably Amsterdam). Checl http://www.thewebandbeyond.nl/ for the 2010 edition (and http://www.thewebandbeyond.nl/2010/website/organisation/ for links to the 2006 and 2008 editions).

Answer (score 5):

Well, there's an [NNG Usability Week in London](http://www.nngroup.com/events/london/agenda.html) in November. I attended last year and it was a great inspiration for my work. 4 of 5 workshops I visited were very interesting plus you meet tons of people working in the same field - that alone would be worth it. So yep, I'd definitely recommend it and I'll attend again this year (San Francisco this time).

Answer (score 4):

The IXDA conference seems to roam around the world. Next year (2012), it will be in Ireland: http://interaction12.ixda.org/

Answer (score 3):

I am biassed because I'll be presenting, but it seems WebExpo Europe (http://webexpo.net/) this September in Prague would be a good fit too.

Comment: there aren't many details on the web page about Web Expo - could you let us know what its about, or some topics that will be there?

Answer (score 2):

[**Design by Fire**](http://designbyfire.nl/2011/) (october, Netherlands) is a really nice one I think. I've been to the last two conferences, going to the next one as well.

What I like is that they cover a quite broad area around interaction/experience design which tries to discover the borders a bit. For example:

- *The Psychology of Creativity* and *Information is Beautiful* in [2010](http://designbyfire.nl/2010/program)
- *Seeing Things in Full Color (While Others See It in Black and White)*, *The Music of Interaction Design* and *Who Dares Wins* in [2009](http://designbyfire.nl/2009/program/)

Since last year they also have [workshops](http://designbyfire.nl/2011/workshops) next to it.

And really nice if you live in the Netherlands, to visit the [bi-monthly cafés](http://designbyfire.nl/cafe), with a talk and some drinks.

Answer (score 2):

There is the annually [uxcamp europe](http://www.uxcampeurope.org/)!. It's organized as a barcamp and has attendees from all over europe. Sessions are held in English.

I visited the uxcamp two times. It was really great. People used to share a lot of insights as you feel that it's more some kind of community event. So you don't try to shine in front of potential clients etc.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoyed the UX Lx in Lisbon last year.
Didn't attend the two workshop days but th conference day was great - fantastic speakers, great talks, very nice organization and attendees from all over the world.

Lisbon is a fantastic city - you might checkout the conference website for the event in 2013 http://www.ux-lx.com/